# Android simple database adapter not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

i am a new android developer. i have some big problems for this reason i dont continue my project. i want to get contacts info then set these info to the sqlite. this step is working but when i try to list in listview dont work here is my code can u help me ?

this is my row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFDAFF7F"
android:padding="8dp">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Text"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dip">
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
 android:textSize="20dip"
 android:textStyle="italic"
 />
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/phone"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="14dip"
 android:textColor="#FF267F00"
 android:paddingLeft="100dip"
 />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout >
```

this is my activity layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my sqlite code

```
package com.example.myprojects;

import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


 public class contacts_nick {

//private static final String TAG = contacts_nick.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
public static final String KEY_PHONE="phone";
public static final String KEY_NICK="nick";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="mydatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="Contacts";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    //To create db
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " (" +KEY_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_PHONE+" TEXT, "+KEY_NICK+" TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}



public contacts_nick(Context c){
    ourContext=c;
}

public contacts_nick open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper=new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long insert (String displayName, String phoneNumber) throws SQLException {

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, displayName);
    cv.put(KEY_PHONE, phoneNumber);     
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getData() throws SQLException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns =new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PHONE};
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result="";

    int id=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    int name=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int phone=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result=result+c.getString(id)+","+c.getString(name)+" "+c.getString(phone)+"\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public String search(int l) throws SQLException{

    String[] columns =new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PHONE};
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,KEY_ID +"="+l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name=c.getString(1);
        return name;

    }
    return null;
}

public int getrowcount(String name,String phone){
    int result;
    String[] columns =new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PHONE};
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,KEY_NAME +"="+"'"+name+"'"+" AND "+KEY_PHONE+"="+ "'"+phone+"'", null, null, null, null);

    result=c.getCount();
    return result;

}

public void update(long id, String name, String phone) throws SQLException{

    ContentValues cvUpdate=new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_ID,id);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME,name);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_PHONE,phone);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
}

public void delete(long l) throws SQLException{

    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID+"="+l, null);
}

public Cursor getAllData () {
     ourDatabase=ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     String[] columns =new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PHONE};
    Cursor cur=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns, null,null, null, null, null);
    return cur;
}
}
```

and this is my main_activity

```
package com.example.myprojects;

 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.ContactsContract;
 import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public class edit_contacts extends ListActivity {

cursor customadapter;
TextView contactView;
TextView s1;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    contactView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     s1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    boolean diditwork=true;
    try{
    Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contacts_nick entry=new contacts_nick(this);
            entry.open();
            if(entry.getrowcount(displayName,phoneNumber)==0){
                entry.insert(displayName,phoneNumber);
                entry.close();
            }
            else{
                Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                 d.setTitle("Error");
                 TextView tv=new TextView(this);
                 tv.setText("KAYIT VAR");
                 d.setContentView(tv);
                 d.show();
                 entry.close();
            }
     }
    }
     catch(Exception e){
         diditwork=false;   
         String error =e.toString();
         Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
         d.setTitle("Sorun Var");
         TextView tv=new TextView(this);
         tv.setText(error);
         d.setContentView(tv);
         d.show();
     }
     finally{
         if(diditwork){
             Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
             d.setTitle("Tebrikler");
             TextView tv=new TextView(this);
             tv.setText("Başaralı");
             d.setContentView(tv);
             d.show();
         }
     }
  contacts_nick info=new contacts_nick(this);

    Cursor c = info.getAllData();
    String[] columns = new String[] { contacts_nick.KEY_ID, contacts_nick.KEY_NAME,contacts_nick.KEY_PHONE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.phone };

    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    ListAdapter simpCurAdap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, c, columns, to,0);
    setListAdapter(simpCurAdap);


    }


}
```

Comment: please add the error details from logcat

Answer (score 0):

`String[] columns = new String[] { contacts_nick.KEY_ID, contacts_nick.KEY_NAME,contacts_nick.KEY_PHONE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.phone };`

You are mapping out three variables but only onto two views.

Comment: Edit your post with the logcat. Otherwise it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

May be have this errors:

try this

```
contacts_nick entry=new contacts_nick(this);
                entry.open();

    Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                if(entry.getrowcount(displayName,phoneNumber)==0){
                    entry.insert(displayName,phoneNumber);
                }
                else{
//this code be running main activity send to onpause state.so you do better way
                    Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                     d.setTitle("Error");
                     TextView tv=new TextView(this);
                     tv.setText("KAYIT VAR");
                     d.setContentView(tv);
                     d.show();

                }
         }

        }
         catch(Exception e){
//this code be running main activity send to onpause state.so you do better way
             diditwork=false;   
             String error =e.toString();
             Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
             d.setTitle("Sorun Var");
             TextView tv=new TextView(this);
             tv.setText(error);
             d.setContentView(tv);
             d.show();
         }
         finally{
             if(diditwork){
//this code be running main activity send to onpause state.so you do better way
                 Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                 d.setTitle("Tebrikler");
                 TextView tv=new TextView(this);
                 tv.setText("Başaralı");
                 d.setContentView(tv);
                 d.show();
             }
         }

//use global objects,and  you didnot call open method so didnot get value,that is problem i think

        Cursor c = entry.getAllData();
        String[] columns = new String[] { contacts_nick.KEY_ID, contacts_nick.KEY_NAME,contacts_nick.KEY_PHONE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.phone };

        //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter simpCurAdap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, c, columns, to,0);
        setListAdapter(simpCurAdap);


        }

@override 
Public onStop(){
super.onStop()

//close finally
if(entry!=null)
       entry.close();
}
```

refer this llink:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html